# Need to run a GitLab pipeline job if a prior job succeeds

Tags: gitlab

I have a project in GitLab that has jobs in the pipeline to build the image, run unit tests and push the built image to a repository. I would like to set it up with the following conditions:

1. The push job needs the build job (for it to build successfully, and I assume for the build artifacts).
2. The push job does not need anything from the test job, but should not run if the test job fails.

Here is the gitlab-ci.yaml:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - release

variables:
  IMAGE_NAME: prometheus-metrics-and-rules
  IMAGE_TAG: $CI_PIPELINE_ID

...

build-image:
  stage: build
  extends:
    - .kaniko-build
  variables:
    DOCKERFILE: Dockerfile
    KUBERNETES_MEMORY_REQUEST: 2Gi
    KUBERNETES_MEMORY_LIMIT: 2Gi

run-unit-tests:
  stage: test
  extends:
    - .kaniko-build
  variables:
    DOCKERFILE: Unit-Tests.Dockerfile
    KUBERNETES_MEMORY_REQUEST: 1Gi
    KUBERNETES_MEMORY_LIMIT: 1Gi
  after_script:
    - mkdir -p test/surefire-reports
    - cp -r /app-build/target/surefire-reports ./test
  artifacts:
    when:
      always
    paths:
      - test/surefire-reports
    reports:
      junit:
        - test/surefire-reports/*.xml
          
push-to-harbor:
  stage: release
  extends:  
    - .release-local-image
  variables:
    SOURCE_IMAGE_NAME: $IMAGE_NAME
    SOURCE_IMAGE_TAG: $CI_PIPELINE_ID
    TARGET_PROJECT: phactory-images
    TARGET_IMAGE_NAME: $IMAGE_NAME
    TARGET_IMAGE_TAG: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  needs:
    - build-image
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED == "true"
```

As you can see, the `run-unit-tests` job produces test artifacts, which are available in GitLab for inspection and download. Also, the `push-to-harbor` job needs the `build-image` job.

I need the `push-to-harbor` job to not run if the `run-unit-tests` job fails. I tried adding
`run-unit-tests` to the `needs` list for `push-to-harbor`, but that had undesirable results in that the image pushed was *not* the executable image of the app. When I removed the need on `run-unit-tests`, it is back in the correct form. However, the push job kicks in immediately after the build job succeeds and pushes the image. In the meantime the test job is also running, but regardless of the outcome, the image has always been pushed.

**UPDATE** (5/30/2023):

As requested, here are the Docker files. The base images used in each Docker file are RHEL. I have included the variable definitions from `.gitlab-ci.yaml`. Not sure how to get the `$CI_PIPELINE_ID`. Wouldn't that always be changing?

Dockerfile:

```
##################
FROM <redacted>/base-images/ubi9-openjdk-11 AS build
##################

# Install Maven (which installs its own Java distribution).
RUN dnf -y upgrade
RUN dnf install -y maven.noarch

WORKDIR /app-build

COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src

# Build and package application. Deliberately do not run tests.
RUN mvn clean install -DskipTests

##################
FROM <redacted>/base-images/ubi9-openjdk-11
##################

ARG BCRCA

ARG crt_file="/tmp/BCRCA.crt"

# Place BCRCA data into temp file.
RUN echo "$BCRCA" > ${crt_file}

# OpenJDK security certificates file path for RHEL.
ARG cacerts-path="/etc/java/java-11-openjdk/java-11-openjdk-11.0.18.0.10-2.el9_1.x86_64/lib/security/cacerts"

# Import BCRCA certificate into JDK keystore.
RUN keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias bcrca -file ${crt_file} \
  -keystore ${cacerts-path} -storepass <redacted>

# Verify BCRCA installed.
RUN keytool -list -keystore ${cacerts-path} -alias bcrca -noprompt -storepass <redacted>

# Remove temp file.
RUN rm ${crt_file}

WORKDIR /app

# Copy application jar file from build image.
COPY --from=build /app-build/target/prometheus-metrics-ref-1.1.1.jar /app/app.jar

COPY styles.css .
COPY promql-keywords.json .

EXPOSE 8080

ENV PROMETHEUS_API_URL=""

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java -jar app.jar ${0} ${@}"]
```

Unit-Tests.Dockerfile

```
##################
FROM <redacted>/base-images/ubi9-openjdk-11 AS build
##################

# Install Maven (which installs its own Java distribution).
RUN dnf -y upgrade
RUN dnf install -y maven.noarch

WORKDIR /app-build

COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src

# Build and test.
RUN mvn clean test
```

Comment: Can you provide both the dockerfiles, $IMAGE_NAME and $CI_PIPELINE_ID value into the question, this will help to investigate a solution by the community.